# Copy range based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a macro to copy only a range of Cells that has data and ignore cells with a value of `NA`

I have built a helper tool to ensure data gathered from multiple sources are placed in the correct corresponding columns, then from there I copy and paste those columns into a master worksheet. The Range these values are populated in are `A3` through `R` and In column `R` is a `Vlookup`.

I want to write a macro so I can press a macro enabled button to copy the cells in that range and end where the `Vlookup` stops returning a value. So far I have been able to write it so it copies to the end of the `Vlookup` but it is still gathering results that include the formula in `R`.

Currently Written:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range(ws.[A:R], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp)).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW I usually do not say this but seems like you may not know how to mark an asnwer as solved. Do not edit the question and type `solved` there. Use the proper way as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

One way.

1. Use Autofilter.
2. Filter out the values which are not `#N/A`
3. Copy the filtered range in one go.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, filteredrng As Range
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lrow = .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A3:R" & lrow)

        With rng
           .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
            Set filteredrng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        If Not filteredrng Is Nothing Then
            '~~> COPY RANGE CODE HERE
        End If

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I plugged this in and it is selecting and copying correctly now, However when I paste from what it is copying it is causing it to paste the selected cells and blank cells to row 104888. Any idea why it is doing that opposed to only pasting the selected cells?

Comment: `'~~> COPY RANGE CODE HERE` if you replace this with `Debug.Print filteredrng.Addres`, what do you see?

Comment: Solved: I had to add .End(xlUp) to my range code. Thank you for the help I had been trying to figure this out for a while